# Accessing an nginx webserver on CentOS7 VM hosted on Virtualbox in Windows 10

Tags: windows, nginx, virtualbox

**Setup:**

A single CentOS 7.1 VM running on a Windows 10 Pro server (preview version 10074), inside Virtualbox 5 beta 4 (also tested on 4.3.8). Using nginx/1.9.0, to serve static HTML files.

The VM is connected to my intranet using the NAT setting within Virtualbox. I have forwarded ports 22, 80 and 443 from the server to the VM using the standard Virtualbox settings.

**Problem:**

Within the VM, I can use curl to fetch any page (`curl localhost` brings back the expected result). However, if I try to fetch the page from the host Windows server or any other clients of the intranet - either by IP or localhost on the host, I get "cannot connect" or "connection reset" errors.

Using netstat on the VM, I have validated that nginx is listening on ports 80 and 443 on both 0.0.0.0 and [::]. I have also checked on the Windows server that ports 80 and 443 are unused when the VM isn't running and they are being listened on when it is.

Checking the logs produced by nginx, access.log contains only my curl requests  - and nothing relevant appears in my error.log.

However, I am also running sshd on the server (on port 22) and can connect to that from any machine on my intranet (and externally when I forward the ports on my internet router), so I don't believe this is a firewall issue.

**Attempted solutions:**

I have tried both opening Windows firewall to allow incoming connections to ports 80/443, as well as adding Virtualbox to the program exceptions. I have also tried disabling the firewall completely.

I have tried moving to ports > 1000 on the host server - but since port 22 seems to work fine that doesn't make much sense.

Unfortunately, I cannot change my VM connection from NAT to any other type. Virtualbox doesn't seem to support adapter bridging in Windows 10 yet (I've tried multiple reinstalls and the new beta release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use `firewall-cmd` to allow http and https traffic through the VM's firewall. Older versions of CentOS would use `iptables`.